# How to make "for..in" in loop wait for a function to execute in swift?

Tags: swift, for-loop

I am creating a personal playlist in my app using songs that I am pulling from the Spotify SDK. Spotify songs have a uri which makes it so you can only play the tracks with the Spotify player which takes a single string uri and plays it, but I have an entire array of track URI's. To solve this I created a `for..in` loop to play each individual song, but what happens is it iterates through the entire array and only plays the last track uri in the array.

*My question is:* Is there a way to have the `for..in` loop wait for each item to finish playing before going through the rest of the array?

[image: array of track uri's]

[image: function that plays each individual URI]

Comment: You should add the code to your post (using the code formatting) instead of linking an image. This will allow others to easily read it or copy/paste to test a solution.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. I just fixed the image tags in your question. However, please to not post your code as images. Instead, provide them as text.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to play the songs sequentially (like a playlist), you need to add them a serial `DispatchQueue`. The serial queue will ensure that only one item is executed inside it at a time and hence only one of the asynchronous requests will execute at a time, meaning that each iteration of the for loop will wait for the previous one to finish.

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "serial")
for song in playAllSongs{
    queue.async{
        //put all code here that you had inside the for loop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a `for...in` loop to play all songs. Even if you use a synchronous block I'm not sure it will works.
A solution is to listen a `Notification` or to have a completion block called when a song is ended. Then you just have to play the next one in the array.